# startProcessInstanceByKey not working in activiti suite (alfresco activiti enterprise)

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn

I migrated from activiti explorer (community version) to alfresco activiti enterprise.
Everything went ok, but now when a process starts a new TTSProcess with the following code:

```
runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("TTSProcess", variables);
```

I get the following error:
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiObjectNotFoundException: no processes deployed with key 'TTSProcess'

This works on the activiti explorer instance...but not on the Alfresco activiti enterprise suite

I renamed my processes from bpmn20.xml to bpmn but with no success.

Please help me out,

thank you

---

The exact steps i did:

I created an app (in activiti-app UI) with the processes I need.
After that, I published the app.
I can see that my app is deployed (in activiti-admin UI) and my first process starts to run.
The second process "TTSProcess" instance that I want to start is deployed (see screenshot)
I've uploaded 2 screenshots to show it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/niP05.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHt0m.jpg

The activiti engine still doesn't want to start up my TTSProcess by key...

Note: I'm using an H2 database

Also important: startProcessInstanceByID works

Comment: Have you migrated to standalone activiti enterprise or to Alfresco Enterprise in which activiti engine is embedded ?

Comment: Alfresco enterprise activiti

Comment: Have cloned your previous environment and then upgraded to Enterprise or simply ported config and extension elements without the actual existing DB ?

Comment: I did the second option! btw: startProcessInstanceByID works, but i really need to get it working by key

Comment: Is there any way you would have corrupted caches? I was just checking the activiti code and unfortunately that would be the only viable explanation as far as I can guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the tenant_id when calling the startProcessInstanceByKey to get it work. The API has an startProcessInstanceByKey overload where you can add the tenant_id

Answer (score 0):

If you are pretty sure that your alfresco activiti engine points to the same DB as your activiti explorer engine, then it could be a problem in your deployed process. Open your file and double check your process definition:

```
<process id="TTSProcess" name="TTS Process name" isExecutable="true">
...
</process>
```

The important attribute is id="**TTSProcess**", that's what activiti takes as the key in the API

`runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("TTSProcess", variables);`

Comment: Does it has something to do with the H2 database I use?

Answer (score 0):

I know my question will be too simple, but we should be sure for the obvious.Did you check your path in your repo? 
For example, you should write,

```
repositoryService.createDeployment()
        .addClasspathResource("diagrams/FinancialReportProcess.bpmn20.xml")
        .deploy();
```

If your dirs is:

src/main/resources/diagrams/FinancialReportProcess.bpmn20.xml

You have to add the package, which include your process.

Lastly you should rename your process .bmpn20.xml again.